# Huge Black Box while debugging app but not in design

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, devexpress, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting a huge black box, but I can't figure out how it got there.

Wow, sorry about the lack of detail on this.

I am not getting the box in design mode on the IDE (VS 2013), but do get it when I debug the application.

As far as additional detail goes, there isn't much. I've attached what I see in VS2013.
[image: The Black Box]

[image: VS2013 in Design no Box]

Comment: What component is place there?

Comment: There are no components in that exact place. above it is a Ribbon Control and below it is a XtraScrollabale control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the split panel is getting resized to the position of the splitter.  Are you trying to preserve the splitter's position between runs of the application?  If you are you may be restoring it incorrectly.  It looks like you may be setting the panel's .top property to the saved position of the splitter instead of the actual splitter, or something similar to that.

Comment: I sincerely apologize, although removing some of the code that was restoring the layout did correct the issue on my machine in debugging and release, I've now found that on the users machine it is not fixed. (Windows XP for them)

Comment: I'm keeping this as the answer, but it was only half of it. There was a conflict with the auto sizing of the form and the minimum size set on the container for the controls. Really annoying stuff.